# How to pass intent extras to multiple fragment inside Activity viewpager from PreviousActivity

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have Two Activity **Activity A and B**. 
Activity B contain viewpager which has two fragment, **Fragment I** and **Fragment II**. I"m looking a solution to pass two separate intent extras i.e *intent extras_one* and *intentextra_two* from Activity A to B and load first *intent extras* in **Fragment I** and Second *intent_extras* in **Fragment II.**

Is this possible.

Here is my viewpager in Activity B

```html
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Home(), "Fragment I");
        adapter.addFragment(new Grade(), "Fragment II");


        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }
```

I'm using case statement for now to pass arguments in Activity A.

```
        case 0:

                Intent math_strt = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                math_strt.putExtra(EXTRA_URL, "https://api.myjson.com/bins/16mecx");
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(math_strt);

                break;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution, you have to create 2 methods in Activity A

```
1. passIntent1()
private void passIntent1(){
     Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("INTENT_VALUE", "A");
     intent.putExtra("FRAGMENT_A", value for A);
     startActivity(intent);
}

2. passIntent2()
private void passIntent2(){
     Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("INTENT_VALUE", "B");
     intent.putExtra("FRAGMENT_B", value for B);
      startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Now, Inside B Activity, get your Intent

```
    String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("INTENT_VALUE");
    if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
         String FragA =  getIntent().getStringExtra("FRAGMENT_A");
    }else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
         String FragB =  getIntent().getStringExtra("FRAGMENT_B");
   }
```

Now pass the value FragA to Fragment A and FragB to Fragment B

UPDATED CODE BELOW

In Activity use below code to pass Values in fragments.
You have to use Bundle to pass data to fragments

```
Home home = new Home();
Bundle homeBundle = new Bundle();
homeBundle.putString("KEY","VALUE");
// Your Key must same when you get your values in Fragment Home
home.setArguments(homeBundle);
```

Similarly you have do same for Fragment Grade

```
Grade grade = new Grade();
Bundle gradeBundle = new Bundle();
gradeBundle.putString("KEY","VALUE");
grade.setArguments(gradeBundle);
```

Add fragments to adapter

```
adapter.addFragment(home, "Fragment I");
adapter.addFragment(grade, "Fragment II");
```

Now in side Fragment, to get values use below code

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
if(bundle!=null){
    String value = bundle.getString("KEY");
}
```

Hope, now you understand in better way.

Comment: Thanks @Shane I"ll try that out, How to pass intent extras in viewpager fragment .I searched but found nothing on passing data intent extras in fragments inside viewpager adatpers. My code for viewpager is given above.

Comment: @ProAcademy I had update the answer, have look into.

Comment: @yes Shane now I understood completely. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do I pass two methods in case statement? I have updated my question also.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass data to fragments but not using intents but by using bundles so the code has to be modified a little. try the code snippet below

```
    Bundle bundle1,bundle2;

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    Home frag1 = new Home();
    Grade frag2 = new Grade();

    bundle1 = new Bundle();
    bundle1.putString("key",data); //pass the data you want to pass
    bundle2 = new Bundle();
    bundle2.putString("key",data);

    frag1.setArguments(bundle1);//set arguments require a bundle 
    frag2.setArguments(bundle2);//set arguments require a bundle 

    adapter.addFragment(frag1, "Fragment I");
    adapter.addFragment(frag2, "Fragment II");


    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

   //Inside the fragments create another bundle
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String data = b.getString("key");
```

More information about bundle can be found [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a fragmentA in ActivityA, which is in a RecyclerView. I wanted to pass an ID to another fragmentB which is inside ActivityB and is inside a ViewPager. What I did was to pass and Intent from FragmentA to ActivityB

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), EachRoomActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("room_id", data.getId());
 startActivity(intent);
```

Inside the onCreate() method of ActivityB, I got the intentExtra

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String room_id = intent.getStringExtra("room_id");
```

This is where I defined the Viewpager that has my Fragments for the TabLayout.
Inside the ViewPagerAdapter Constructor, I added a requirement for the ID

```
 public EachRoomViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, String room_id) {
    super(fm);
    this.room_id = room_id;
}
```

So at the point I am switching view for the ViewPager, I add the Bundle Extra to the Fragment.

```
 @NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("room_id", room_id);


    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            fragment = new EachRoomMySubscriptionsFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new EachRoomSchedulledEventsFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new EachRoomPreviousEventsFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new EachRoomAllEventsFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

Now, inside the Fragment's OnCreateView() Method, I get the Bundle Extra

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
  if(bundle!=null){
     room_id = bundle.getString("room_id");
  }
```

That's it.